# Matching a file name with a dynamic variable in r

Tags: r

I load my data files manually and name them by Month and year, so my latest file was Nov18.

I need to analyse the last three months of data - currently I change my coding file each month to select the correct three months, but I want to automate the binding of the last three months of data using dynamically created file names.

I can re-create the file name dynamically, but I'm struggling to use this name in my rbind statement

So I load my data as normal

```
   Nov18 <- Read_csv(filepath/"Nov18.csv")
   Oct18 <- Read_csv(filepath/"Oct18.csv")
   Sep18 <- Read_csv(filepath/"Sep18.csv")
```

Next I want to combine these three files together using rbind, selecting only the last 3 months (relative to the data loaded).

Using the dates imported in the last data set, I create the  following variables

```
    lastm =  as.numeric(format.Date(max(Nov18$dates), format = "%m"))
    lastyr=  as.numeric(format.Date(max(Nov18$dates), format = "%y"))
```

Then I create the 3 month/year name formats as follows

```
    M1TY = as.symbol(paste(month.abb[lastm],lastyr,sep=""))
    M2TY = as.symbol(paste(month.abb[lastm-1],lastyr,sep=""))
    M3TY = as.symbol(paste(month.abb[lastm-2],lastyr,sep=""))
```

So my output is

```
    > M1TY
    Nov18
    > M2TY
    Oct18
    > M3TY
    Sep18
```

these match the data file names I have but I struggle to use these to call up the data files

I tried to combine the 3 datafiles using:

```
    Long_term_data <-rbind(M1TY,M2TY,M3TY)
    #and
    Long_term_data <-bind_rows(list(M1TY,M2TY,M3TY))
    #and
    Long_term_data <-rbind(list(M1TY,M2TY,M3TY))
```

But couldn't get any to work for me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You haven't read any files yet. Where do you read the data?

Comment: Thanks for responding - my files are loaded as described at the start of the post, or have I mis-understood your question, do you need the specific files? I was hoping there's a simple step (which I clearly don't understand) about formatting my dynamic month/year names such that R reads them as the file name loaded and rbinds the 3 months together into a new file.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case I think you want to use `M1TY <- get(paste(month.abb[lastm],lastyr,sep=""))` etc...

Comment: Many thanks, that has worked for me.  Much appreciated